# summary.lm not working: Error in diag(R): (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

Tags: r

I do not know how to proceed with this, so I am counting on your help. Bad thing is: I do not know how to provide you with a reproducible example, because it might run on your systems.

Here is what I get (it is VERY basic and this ran like a million times in the past for me, too):

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100))
mod <- lm(a ~ b, data = df)
print(mod)
# works...
summary(mod)
Error in diag(R) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

I do not know where to start here. Here is a list of my loaded packages in case that helps:

```
(.packages())
[1] "data.table" "plotrix"    "lubridate"  "graphics"   "grDevices"  "datasets"   "XML"        "utils"      "RCurl"      "bitops"    
[11] "stringr"    "sciplot"    "stats"      "methods"    "base"
```

And here is the R.Version() output:

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "2.2"

$year
[1] "2015"

$month
[1] "08"

$day
[1] "14"

$`svn rev`
[1] "69053"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"

$nickname
[1] "Fire Safety"
```

Thanks for your help! Please comment if you need any more information on my R session...

EDIT: It works fine now. I don't know what I did to make it work. Sorry for bothering you...

Comment: did you install/update a new package between the times where it worked and doesn't work anymore ?

Comment: First step of debugging: Restart R and run the code with only base packages loaded and see if the error is still there.

Comment: I excluded each package separately from being loaded during R startup. It then worked with every combination. Now I'm back to normal startup and it still works. I did reboot Windows in between, maybe that did the trick. I don't get it. Thanks for your time!